# Get top xyz from Elastic GET API

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana, elk, elasticsearch-net

I have a requirement to delete documents from Elastic Index. I tried following, but it gives timeouts due to the size of the documents.

```
POST my-index-000001/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Therefore, I'm thinking of getting top 5000 record `ids` and send batched delete query. Can anyone help me on getting top 5000 ids from elastic API (no need to retrieve entire document object)? or is there any other way to handle this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `wait_for_completion=false`

[from here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-task-api)

```
    POST my-index-000001/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed&wait_for_completion=false
     {
      "query": {
      "match_all": {}
     }
   }
```

> If the request contains wait_for_completion=false, Elasticsearch performs some preflight checks, launches the request, and returns a task you can use to cancel or get the status of the task. Elasticsearch creates a record of this task as a document at .tasks/task/${taskId}. When you are done with a task, you should delete the task document so Elasticsearch can reclaim the space.

Run `GET /_tasks/your-task-id` to see its status

Comment: And when the task is done it will not be visible anymore with the `_tasks` endpoint. You'll need to check it with `.tasks/task/your-task-id`

Comment: @Val `.tasks` index.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @all thanks for the suggestions. I will check and let you know. Thanks!